# Django-import-export library - No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp5bcxsx9p'

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a problem with the django-import-export library because when I try to import excel or csv files it gives me error 500, and the error returned is the following

FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp5bcxsx9p'

and the error comes from django-import-export library in the file import_export/tmp_storages.py in _open()

```
    def _open(self, mode="r"):

        if self.name:

            return open(self.get_full_path(), mode, encoding=self.encoding) <----

        else:

            tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

            self.name = tmp_file.name

            return tmp_file
```

this is the code in the Django admin of the model that im trying to import info

```
class ProductForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):
    def get_queryset(self, value, row, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(value, row, *args, **kwargs)
        return qs.filter(shop__tpc_shop=int(row['ID TIENDA']), sku=row['SKU'].upper().strip())


class StockResource(resources.ModelResource):
    shop = Field(
        column_name='ID TIENDA',
        attribute='shop',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Shop, 'tpc_shop')
    )

    product = Field(
        column_name='SKU',
        attribute='product',
        widget=ProductForeignKeyWidget(Product, 'sku')
    )

    units = Field(
        column_name='UNIDADES',
        attribute='units',
        widget=IntegerWidget(),
        default=0,
    )

    threshold_units = Field(
        column_name='UMBRAL',
        attribute='threshold_units',
        widget=IntegerWidget(),
        default=10,
    )

    location = Field(
        column_name='LOCALIZACION',
        attribute='location',
        widget=OurCharWidget(),
        default='No location',
    )

    @classmethod
    def get_error_result_class(self):
        """
        Returns the class used to store an error resulting from an import.
        """
        return SimpleError

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        use_transactions = True
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        import_id_fields = ('product',)
        fields = ('id', 'units', 'threshold_units', 'location')

    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        row['SKU'] = str(row['SKU']).strip()

        try:
            shop = Shop.objects.get(tpc_shop=int(row['ID TIENDA']))
            product = Product.objects.get(shop=shop, sku=row['SKU'])
            stock = product.stock
            old_units = stock.units
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            old_units = 0
        except Stock.DoesNotExist:
            old_units = 0

        new_units = int(row.get('UNIDADES', 0)) + old_units

        row['UNIDADES'] = new_units

        super().before_import_row(row, row_number=row_number, **kwargs)

    def skip_row(self, instance, original, row, import_validation_errors=None):
        if not instance.product:
            return True


@admin.register(Stock)
class StockAdmin(ImportMixin, SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id', 'tienda', linkify('product'), 'units',
        'reserved_units', 'updated_at'
    )
    raw_id_fields = ('product',)
    readonly_fields = ('units_sold', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    search_fields = ('product__sku',)
    list_filter = ('product__shop__name',)
    ordering = ('-updated_at',)
    resource_class = StockResource
    actions = [download_stock_template, remove_reserved_units, remove_all_units]

    download_stock_template.short_description = 'Descargar plantilla de stock'

    def tienda(self, obj):
        return obj.product.shop

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.select_related('product__shop')
        return qs
```

Does anyone know how I can permanently solve it? That mistake makes me tired

I tried to use CacheStorage but it doesn't work either. I don't understand why this error occurs. Sometimes it is solved when I delete the browser cookies and try to import, but it is not a definitive solution because the error appears again

Comment: What version of import export are you using, and how is it deployed?  If it is in a multi container environment the file might not exist.  More info in [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#import-confirmation).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply... I'm using django-import-export 3.3.1. I have my Django application in aws on elastic beanstalk @MatthewHegarty

Comment: I suggest to use django [db cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#database-caching) as this will store the temp file in the db and not on the filesystem, so should resolve this problem.

Comment: I will try it, thank you @MatthewHegarty

Comment: I downgraded from version 3.3.1 to 2.8.0 and it appears to be working fine at the moment, I'll let you know if it crashes again @MatthewHegarty

Comment: Best to get it working with 3.x, 2.x now unsupported.  It should work fine if you follow the docs I linked to.

Comment: Hello again @MatthewHegarty, the problem persisted with version 2.x, I tried to cache the database as you mentioned but the problem still persists. I used django's Database caching, or should I use Filesystem caching? I honestly don't understand, first time using the cache in django

Comment: db caching should work fine.  Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#database-caching) are the best way to start.  If you think you have found an issue with import-export, please raise an issue [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues) and give us as much information as you can so that we can investigate.